# epson epos printer - print two images horizontally android

Tags: android, printing, android-bluetooth, epson

I downloaded the android sdk for epson epos2 printer and I integrate with my application without any problem.
   Now I can print the images or texts vertically one by one. But my problem is I want to print one image and some lines of text next to that image like horizontally. For this format I tried addpageArea(x,y,width,height) addpagebegin(), addpageEnd() and I tried with addPagePosition(x,y) also. These methods also print in vertical format only. Please any one can help me. I spent 2 days for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution?plz share to me

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found the solution for this but no predefined one. By using addpagearea function you have to manually divide the paper according to your need. then inside the page area you can add your strings and images.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think I found the solution for this. u can try to put

addPageDirection(EPOS2_DIRECTION_BOTTOM_TO_TOP)
this will rotate data counterclockwise by 90 degrees

The code will be like this:

```
addPageBegin() // Start Page
addPageArea(x,y,width,height) // Page Area
addPageDirection(EPOS2_DIRECTION_BOTTOM_TO_TOP) // Rotate
addImage() // Image
addPageEnd(); // End Page
```

[This is my reference](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_ios_en/index.php?content_id=113)